# setting default 'SELECTED' in checkbox elements of zend 2 forms

Tags: checkbox, zend-framework2, zend-form

I want to set a default **'selected'** for my checkbox in zend 2.

i tried adding a default

> 'value'=>'selected'

but it does not seem to work.

```
$this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox',
            'name' => 'receiveNewsletters',
            'options' => array(
                'value_options' => array(
                    '1' => 'Untick if you do not want to receive promotional emails',
                ),
                'attributes' => array(
                    'value'=>'selected',
                ),
            ),    

        ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value should be the `checked_value`. By default it is `'1'`

```
$this->add(array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox',
    'name' => 'receiveNewsletters',
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Untick if you do not want to receive promotional emails',
    ),
    'attributes' => array(
        'value' => '1',
    ),
));
```

Comment: I dont see any `checked_value` in this snippet

Comment: hi Gennadiy ,it does not work. i tried your code but it does not work

Comment: @GennadiyLitvinyuk, hey Gennadiy. thank you so much. it works now.